# Meaning of sfr on sheet music

Tags: guitar, notation, classical-music

I have seen this on sheet music before

[image]

But cannot find any definion of what it means. If you can tell me that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just an unusual abbreviation of *sforzando*, which is usually "sfz".  It has effectively the same meaning as an accent.

Comment: "Sforzando" is Italian for "striving" or "straining" or "with force".

Comment: It means much  more than just accent.

Answer (score 1):

As it is, it's not an actual abbreviation that's accepted. As the others have said, sfortzato or sfortzando are the probable connotations, both meaning a sudden sound,but subtly different, in amongst 'ordinary' playing. I would achieve this by lifting the strings, and letting them go, so they hit the fret/fingerboard. This gives a percussive sound in comparison to plucking in an ordinary way. That's sf or sfz on guitar.

The only sfr is a French telecom service.

Answer (score 0):

It means sforzato which in English means "force" or "forced".